# SQL Replace blank value in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, case, conditional-statements

I have two tables:

Student (ks2en, ks2ma, ks2av)

Subject (name)

I have the following conditional statement which depending on the subject lists the values in the student columns. These are then subsequently grouped by their respective student column.

In any combination I would like to replace '' blank values in the result set with 'No KS2'.

Here is my case statement which conditionally selects the appropriate column from the student table base on the subject name in the subject table.

```
   CASE 
      WHEN COALESCE(Name, '') = 'English' THEN
        [Ks2en]
      WHEN COALESCE(Name, '') = 'Mathematics' THEN
        [Ks2ma]
      ELSE
        [Ks2av]
   END AS KS2
```

Example data:

```
ks2en
2a
2a
3a
4c

5a
3a
2a

1c
```

When the subject name is 'English' then the following results are displayed:

```
KS2
No KS2
1c
2a
3a
4c
5a
```

Just to be clear, don't worry about ordering, grouping or the conditional element of the statement as I have got these all working. It's just replacing blank values with 'No KS2' so that it displays as one of the groups of values in the results set as above.

Comment: I'd like to replace blank values with the value 'No KS2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
CASE Name
WHEN 'English' THEN
    CASE WHEN [Ks2en]=NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
        'No KS2'
    ELSE
        [Ks2en]
    END
WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
    CASE WHEN [Ks2ma]=NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
        'No KS2'
    ELSE
        [Ks2ma]
    END
ELSE
    CASE WHEN [Ks2av]=NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
        'No KS2'
    ELSE
        [Ks2av]
    END
END AS KS2
```

Removed inner `COALESCE` as they were not usefull!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I've tried this and the grouped results are still showing as blanks.

Comment: You probably have empty strings in your data... So, I would replace empty strings with null.

Comment: Hi, yes the data has empty values. Not sure if that came across in the question. Is that what you mean? I'm trying to replace out these empty values with the string 'No KS2'.

Comment: What I mean is that your empty values are `TEXT` with zero length. I though they were `NULL`. `''` is different from `NULL`. `NULL` has many options to deal with (`COALESCE` in this case). Empty `TEXT` must be handled differently.

Comment: I see. Yes its text with zero length. Thanks for making that clear for me.